# Using the data from a for loop as a table in the From in a Select

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am converting some code in Access over to Oracle, and one of the queries in Access uses a table that I am unable to use in Oracle. I am unable to create new tables, so I am trying to figure out a way to use the logic behind the table in the FOR section of my select.

The logic of the table is similar to:

```
FOR i = 1 To 100
    number = number + 1
    .AddNew
    !tbl_number = number
NEXT i
```

I'm trying to convert this to oracle, and so far I have:

```
FOR i in 1 .. 100 LOOP
   number := number + 1;
   --This is where I am stuck; How do I simulate the table part
END LOOP;
```

I was thinking a cursor or a record would be the answer, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement that. In the end I basically want to have:

```
SELECT
   table.number
FROM
   (
     --My for loop logic
   ) table
```

*EDIT*

The calculation is a bit more complicated; that was just an example. They aren't actually sequential, and there isn't really a pattern to rows.

*EDIT*

Here is a more complicated version of the for loop which is closer to what I'm actually doing:

```
FOR i in 1 .. 100 LOOP

   number1 := number1 + 7;
   number2 := (number2 + 8) / number1;
   --This is where I am stuck; How do I simulate the table part
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a recursive query (assuming you are on Oralce 11gR2 or later):

```
with example(idx, number1, number2) as (
  -- Anchor Section
  select 1
       , 1 -- initial value
       , 2 -- initial value
    from dual

  union all

  -- Recursive Section
  select prev.idx + 1
       , prev.number1 + 7
       , (prev.number2 + 8) / prev.number1
    from example prev
   where prev.idx < 100  -- The Guard
)
select * from example;
```

In the Anchor section set all the values for your first record.  Then in the Recursive section setup the logic to determine the next records values as a function of the prior records values.

The Anchor section could select the initial values from some other table rather than being hard coded as in my example.

The recursive section needs to select from the named subquery (in this case example) but may also join to other tables as needed.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Now I just have to extrapolate on this and I should be golden! You are 10/10 Sentinel, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a set with sequential integer numbers. Maybe you can use this (for Oracle 10g and above):

```sql
SELECT 
  ROWNUM NUM
FROM 
  DUAL D1, 
  DUAL D2
CONNECT BY
  (D1.DUMMY = D2.DUMMY AND ROWNUM <= 100)
```

Comment: The calculation is a bit more complicated; that was just an example. They aren't actually sequential, and there isn't really a pattern to rows.

Comment: Please, provide more details about your problem.

Comment: I can't actually show the calculation, but aside from that the code above is pretty much line for line the same. I guess I could make a little less simple example of the calculations.

I guess the big thing is that in Access a table is being generated with logic without refering to any other tables.

In Oracle I need to refer to this table, but since it is in access I can't. I also can't create a new table in the oracle environment. 

Is there a way to copy the logic that generates the access table in the FOR section of my Oracle select, so that I can select from the table?